# How to get just the infomation with the highest value

Tags: sql, sql-server, max

Ok so I am pulling from a table to keeps old data as well as the new data. I need just the player_Id and the Rank_id but I only want one record and I need that record to be the one with the highest rank ID. Rank id ranges from 0 to 6. With the code I thought would work I get a record for each player for every rank they have been. I know there must be a way to fix this but I am not sure how.

Below is the code I was trying to use.

```
Select Player_ID
,Max(Rank_ID) as Rank_ID

From dbo.Tiered_Rank_Player

Group by Player_Id
,Rank_ID
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? A descending order and limit to 1 record will do it.

Comment: ...Oh, the `dbo.` probably implies MS SQL Server (which uses `TOP N`)?

Comment: I am still really new to all this so could you explain to me what RDBMS means. based on the second comment I am guessing you wanted to know I was using SSMS 2008 to pull from a SQL 2000 Server is that right?

Comment: RDBMS = "Relational DataBase Management System" which means the database vendor Oracle, MySQL, MS SQL Server, Access, PostgreSQL, etc.

Comment: So in the future I should mention I am using MS SQL Server then. Thanks will do.

Comment: Yep, there's a tag for each RDBMS. It matters which because their implementations differ in a lot of areas. Many responses will end up being RDBMS-specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose, you are looking for this if you want a record for each player with his highest rank till now:

```
Select Player_ID, Max(Rank_ID) as Rank_ID From dbo.Tiered_Rank_Player 
   Group by Player_Id
```

Comment: No idea why this got downvoted this fixed the issue. I had just gotten so used to putting the columns in the group by that I had the Rank_ID listed there as well by removing that part as suggested here it fixed the issue.

Comment: Maybe, someone didn't read the question properly. I am glad it solved your problem... :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are using SQL Server...

But you should be able to the do the likes of

```
Select TOP 1 Player_ID, Max(Rank_ID) as Rank_ID
From dbo.Tiered_Rank_Player
Group by Player_Id,Rank_ID
```

You can do any combo of

```
TOP Number
TOP 5
```

or

```
TOP Percentage
TOP 5 PERCENT
```